# Loading AJAX response without DIV

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a jsp calling AJAX response of which contains script tag

```
<script>
var globalvar =
var globalvar2 = 

</script>
```

I load the response to a DIV element. However, any variables defined in script tag of DIV are not accessible in other script tags in the body of jsp.
Can someone suggest how to get the script from AJAX response accessible to other script on the page?

Comment: The visibility of variables in scripts has nothing to do with what HTML element the script tag is loaded into.

Answer (score 0):

I Think you have a timing problem.
a better way to store your variables is in a hidden input field.

```
  <input type="hidden" id="foobar" value="test">
  <script>
    var myVariable = document.getElementByID('foobar').value; // to get

    document.getElementByID('foobar').value = 'test' // to set
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the ordering of your JS scripts. If you're declaring those vars below a script that needs access to them, they will not be available. Take this scenario for example.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jsFunctions.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var globalvar = "test";
</script>
<body>
</html>
```

If you call a function in jsFunctions.js and try to use the globalvar variable, it won't work. Instead, it needs to be created above any script which you need access within the document.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript'>
var globalvar = "test";
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jsFunctions.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<body>
</html>
```